# Using spread operator in a .map to not mutate the state but return updated state from function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6

I have this function that is called to show or hide checkbox options upon clicking "see more" or "see less". I was told this mutated the redux state

```
const getVisibleBrandOptions = (options = [], page) => {
  let length = 0;
  let visibleLength = 0;
  options.map((opt) => {
    if (length > page * OPTIONS_PER_PAGE) {
      opt.hidden = true;
    }
    if (length <= page * OPTIONS_PER_PAGE) {
      opt.hidden = false;
      visibleLength++;
    }
    length++;
    return opt;
  });
  options.loadMoreLabel = visibleLength >= page * OPTIONS_PER_PAGE ? "See more" : "See less";
  return options;
};
```

So I modified it to this by using a spread operator and setting `const option = { ... opt };` But the issue with this is that it pretty much just returns the original object without the modifications ie. `option.hidden`

```
const getVisibleBrandOptions = (options = [], page) => {
  let length = 0;
  let visibleLength = 0;
  options.map((opt) => {
    const option = { ...opt };
    if (length > page * OPTIONS_PER_PAGE) {
      option.hidden = true;
    }
    if (length <= page * OPTIONS_PER_PAGE) {
      option.hidden = false;
      visibleLength++;
    }
    length++;
    return option;
  });
  options.loadMoreLabel = visibleLength >= page * OPTIONS_PER_PAGE ? "See more" : "See less";
  return options;
};
```

Comment: What were you trying to achieve by making a shallow copy of `opt`? Also you don't really need `.map()` for this; you've no need to make a new array, you're just modifying properties of objects in the array. You're not even paying attention to the return value from `.map()`.

Comment: An array shouldn't have a `.loadMoreLabel` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.prototype.map()` returns a mapped copy of the original array, which you are ignoring here. You haven't actually mutated the `options` object you're returning at all. You could simply replace `.map(...)` with `.forEach(...)` to operate on the original array, or you could do it how you tried to do it with immutability:

```js
const getVisibleBrandOptions = (options = [], page) => {
  const limit = page * OPTIONS_PER_PAGE;
  const newOptions = options.map((opt, index) => ({
    ...opt,
    hidden: index > limit;
  }));

  newOptions.loadMoreLabel = options.length > limit ? "See more" : "See less";
  return newOptions;
}
```

Also, you seem to be putting a named property, `loadMoreLabel`, on an array, which I don't think you meant to do! Not to mention it will never be `true`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks really strange that you are setting options.loadMoreLabel on the array but besides that, you are not doing anything with the returned array from the map. Check the code below, it should work

```
const getVisibleBrandOptions = (options = [], page) => {
      let length = 0;
      let visibleLength = 0;
      const opts = options.map(opt => {
        const option = { ...opt };
        if (length > page * OPTIONS_PER_PAGE) {
          option.hidden = true;
        }
        if (length <= page * OPTIONS_PER_PAGE) {
          option.hidden = false;
          visibleLength++;
        }
        length++;
        return option;
      });
      opts.loadMoreLabel = visibleLength >= page * OPTIONS_PER_PAGE ? 'See more' : 'See less';
      return opts;
    };
```